# Different classification accuracy every time I train models on the same dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am training three different classifiers (KNN with k=1,3,5,7,9,11,13 - Naive Bayes - Logistic) on the same dataset using the same features extractor and I am comparing the accuracies to determine which classifier is better on the dataset. 
However, every time I train these models (re-execute the whole code on the same dataset) I get different values of accuracy for each model. 
Is this normal? Is there a way to obtain only one value of accuracy for each model?

This is my whole code (I am sorry but some comments are in Italian):

```
from skimage import io as sio
from skimage.feature import daisy
from dataset import Dataset
from time import time
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans as KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

dataset=Dataset('dataset')
classes=["edifici","quadri","sculture"]

print(dataset.getLength())
#dividiamo in test set e training set
training_set, test_set = dataset.splitTrainingTest(0.7) #70% training, 30% test

#------------Extraction of features and building of the vocabulary
#estraiamo tutte le features dalle immagini del dataset
training_local_features = extract_features(training_set)

#inizializziamo l'oggetto "KMeans" impostando il numero di centroidi 
kmeans = KMeans(500) #avviamo il kmeans sulle feature estratte  
kmeans.fit(training_local_features) 
#i centroidi dei cluster ottenuti dall'algoritmo k-means sono conservati all'interno di k-means cluster
kmeans.cluster_centers_.shape

#codifichiamo le classi piuttosto che con delle stringhe, con degli indici numerici:
classes_idx=range(len(classes))

#estraggo le features dal training set:
X_training,y_training,paths_training=describe_dataset(training_set,kmeans) 
X_test,y_test,paths_test=describe_dataset(test_set,kmeans)


#Normalization TF-IDF
presence=(X_training>0).astype(int)
df=presence.sum(axis=0)
n=len(X_training)
idf=np.log(float(n)/(1+df))
X_training_tfidf=X_training*idf
X_test_tfidf=X_training*idf
norm=Normalizer(norm='l2')
X_training_tfidf_12=norm.transform(X_training_tfidf)
X_test_tfidf_12=norm.transform(X_test_tfidf)



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------KNN
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNN 

#----------------------------------------------------------------------3NN
nn5 = KNN(3) 
nn5.fit(X_training,y_training) 
predicted_labels=nn5.predict(X_test) 
a = accuracy_score(y_test,predicted_labels) 

M = confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted_labels)

print ("3-NN, accuracy: %0.2f, Confusion Matrix:\n" %a) 
print (M)

#----------------------------------------------------------------NAIVE BAYES

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB as NB
nb=NB()

#alleno il modello
nb.fit(X_training, y_training)
#valutiamo la performance
predicted_labels=nb.predict(X_test)
print("NAIVE BAYES: Accuracy: %0.2f, Confusion Matrix:/n"% accuracy_score(y_test,predicted_labels))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted_labels))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------LOGISTIC

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca=PCA()
pca.fit(X_training)
X_training_pca=pca.transform(X_training)
X_test_pca=pca.transform(X_test)

lr=LogisticRegression() #viene usato il metodo one vs rest di default

lr.fit(X_training_pca,y_training)

p=lr.predict(X_test_pca)
print ("LOGISTI REGRESSION: Accuracy: %0.2f, Confusion matrix:\n" % accuracy_score(y_test,p))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,p))
```

The first time I executed the code I got:

```
3-NN, accuracy: 0.67, Confusion Matrix:
[[ 9  3  4]
 [ 4 11  2]
 [ 3  0 12]]

NAIVE BAYES: Accuracy: 0.83, Confusion Matrix:/n
[[15  0  1]
 [ 2 13  2]
 [ 2  1 12]]

LOGISTI REGRESSION: Accuracy: 0.71, Confusion matrix:
[[13  2  1]
 [ 5 11  1]
 [ 4  1 10]]
```

The second time:

```
3-NN, accuracy: 0.65, Confusion Matrix:
[[11  2  3]
 [ 3 13  1]
 [ 7  1  7]]

NAIVE BAYES: Accuracy: 0.85, Confusion Matrix:/n
[[15  1  0]
 [ 1 14  2]
 [ 1  2 12]]

LOGISTI REGRESSION: Accuracy: 0.79, Confusion matrix:
[[13  0  3]
 [ 0 14  3]
 [ 1  3 11]]
```

I was expecting the results to be the same...

Comment: Hi, your code is very hard to check for me, because it is a bit too long. I see that you are using [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), LogisticRegression offers an option called `random_state` set this option with an arbitrary number like `1234`, and train you model again. Are the results the same?

Comment: If this doesnt work, also check that `dataset.splitTrainingTest(0.7)` produces deterministic results. That means check if `training_set` and `test_set` contain the same values, when executing `dataset.splitTrainingTest(0.7)` twice...

Comment: The question is: this is normal? The only answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the models that you are using have an argument called `random_state`.

Example:

```
KMeans(n_clusters=8, init=’k-means++’, n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=None)

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, fit_intercept=True, random_state=None)
```

**Make sure to define these to be the same** e.g.

```
KMeans(n_clusters=8, init=’k-means++’, n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, fit_intercept=True, random_state=0)
```